# Passing different type of parameters to a JSON in IOS

Tags: ios, json, parameters

I've this problem... I have to pass to a JSON two parameters: one is a simply integer and the other is a structure (practically a Dictionary).
I thought to build a structure like this:

```
NSDictionary *totalRequest = @{
                               @"param1": @"integerValue",
                               @"param2": @{
                                            @"subParam1": @"text1",
                                            @"subParam2": @"text2",
                                            @"subParam3": @"text3",
                                            @"subParam4": @"text4",
                                       },
                               };

NSError *error;
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurl.com/json"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSMutableDictionary* jsonDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:totalRequest];
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest addValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (connectionError) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@",connectionError.description);
        }
        else
        {
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *retData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",[retData objectForKey:@"data"]);
            NSString *errore = [[retData objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"error"];
            if ([errore isEqualToString:@"-30000"]) {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:NSLocalizedString(@"pwderror", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
            }
            if (errore == nil) {
                //MY CODE
        }
    }
}];
```

The problem is that the server returns retData empty....
Is this the correct way to send two parameters (one simply and one complex) to server via JSON?

Thanks to all contributors...

Comment: It depends of the documentation of the Webservice you're using.

Comment: Is a JSON that accept this two parameters:
param1 = 5
 
param2 ={"subParam1":"text1","subParam2":"text2","subParam3":"text3","subParam4":"text4"}